# How to plot Sankey diagrams using X and Y coordinates using Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, sankey-diagram

I would like to plot a Sankey diagram / river plot, similar to this:

[image: Sankey diagram]
<sub>(source: [maartenlambrechts.be](http://www.maartenlambrechts.be/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/PolitiekeVerschuivingen.png))</sub>

I have the data which I used to plot line plots, and I want to use same X and Y vectors to plot a Sankey diagram.

I want to start at X0,Y0 and go through X1,Y1 and so on, ending at Xn,Yn.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sankey diagrams in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620125/sankey-diagrams-in-python)

Comment: @mkierc In the link you shared, it contains list of alternative libraries for sankey.

Comment: I am looking in specific to matplotlib, as how to position sankey nodes at a particular coordinate of x,y.

Comment: I don't think matplotlib can produce "linear" Sankey diagrams like that. A quick Google search turned up several blog posts showing how to achieve a similar result by writing the graph structure to a JSON file, then using R to produce the plot [(e.g. here)](http://spencerboucher.com/fun-with-sankey-diagrams/). That said, are you sure that a Sankey diagram is what you need? The point of a Sankey diagram is that the width of the paths represent the flow quantity, but from your description it seems you only have XY coordinates without any associated weights.

Comment: @ali_m thanks for the information. And yes they are weighted, but the weight remains same throughout.  Here is what exactly I am trying to achieve. https://i.imgsafe.org/35e2a19afc.png . And I guess R is another scripting language. Right now my application is a Qt/C++ application and I have interfaced it with python. So I am looking for a python sankey library.

Comment: @ali_m or any c++ library which can output this   https://i.imgsafe.org/35e2a19afc.png will do.